# How to distinguish radio in html form POST?

Tags: html, forms, http-post

this is a simple html form：

```
<form action="/info" method="post">
    <div >
        <input type="" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" checked > woman
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" > man
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" >Conform</button>
</form>
```

after click submits button, this is post request's body:

[image]

as you can see, this post cannot distinguish if the user is woman or man.

How to conform which box does user choice in this form post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="/info" method="post">
    <div >
        <input type="" name="name">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" checked value="woman"> woman
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="man"> man
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" >Conform</button>
</form>
```

You should be able to get value now

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `value` of each radio input accordingly

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="woman" checked> woman
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="man"> man
```